# Name of file from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I try to load `CODE` and `NAME_IMAGE` from table `IMAGES` to use as name of final jpg...But I don't know how I could use for each image his name and code... do you have an idea?

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("*****");
connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT IMAGE,NAME_IMAGE,CODE FROM IMAGES", connection);
byte[] buffer = (byte[]) command.ExecuteScalar ();
connection.Close();
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\L\Desktop\\" + (CODE) + "_" + (NAME_IMAGE) + ".jpg", FileMode.Create);
fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading multiple columns, and you don't have a `where` clause, so the first problem here is `ExecuteScalar` - that is designed to read the first column of the first row **only**. Since that isn't the case here, you should look at `ExecuteReader` instead. Or a tool that *wraps* readers, for example "dapper":

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("*****"))
{
    var data = connection.Query("SELECT IMAGE,NAME_IMAGE,CODE FROM IMAGES");
    foreach(dynamic row in data)
    {
        byte[] data = row.IMAGE; // yes, as simple as that
        string name = row.NAME_IMAGE;
        //... do something with data / name
    }
}
```

or via raw ADO.NET:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("*****"))
using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IMAGE,NAME_IMAGE,CODE FROM IMAGES";
    connection.Open();
    using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            byte[] data = (byte[])reader["IMAGE"];
            string name = (string)reader["NAME"];
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When i try your first way i have this error: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Query' and no extension method 'Query' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' could be found

Comment: @Kate yes, the first example is via the "dapper" tool - for that to work, you would need to *add dapper* - freely available via Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper - or alternatively, use the second example which is raw ADO.NET